# How to set max lines for Text or RichText?

Tags: flutter

In android, we can set max lines for text view like this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:maxLines="5" />
```

However in flutter, we can do that by adding max height constrains, but we need to know what exactly the height is.

Is there any way we can easily specify the max lines for Text/RichText?

Comment: In my case, I just checked the text on different conditions and used \n for dividing the text

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Edit 2021 - it's possible now

(Hint -  Optional but recommended is to set some overflow with maxLines)

```
        Text(
          'My text',
          maxLines: 4,
          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
        ),


       RichText(
          text: TextSpan(children: ....),
          maxLines: 4,
          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
        ),
```

Comment: Note for anyone visiting this page in 2020: It is supported now. See other answers

Answer (score 50):

Simple using the `maxLines` property

```
Text("Some large text", maxLines: 2)
```

And you can use    `overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis` to insert `...` overflow ellipsis in text

```
Text("Some large text", maxLines: 2, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis)
```

Answer (score 11):

I believe it's supported now:

```
RichText(
    maxLines: 2,
    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis, // TextOverflow.clip // TextOverflow.fade
    text: TextSpan(
        text: 'Hello ',
        style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style,
        children: <TextSpan>[
            TextSpan(text: 'bold', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
            TextSpan(text: ' world!'),
        ],
    ),
)
```

Answer (score -4):

Use simple snippet of code, you can achieve this:

```
Text("Text",
    style: TextStyle(
        fontFamily: "Avenir",
        color: Color(0xff0C64B1),
        fontSize: width * 0.045),
    maxLines: 10)
```

Let me know if you are facing any issues with above. I'd be happy to assist you.